# Castle Windsor and Dynamic Wiring

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I've been a heavy Windsor users for the last several years.  Prior to the Fluent Registration API, I would toggle between Xml Registration and huge piles of AddComponent() code.  We've been happily using the Fluent Registration API and Installers specifically for quite some time now.  I've gotten the impression from various writings like this:

http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.XML-Registration-Reference.ashx

That the Xml Registration approach has fallen out of favor and it wouldn't surprise me if it were marked for deprecation at some point in the near future.

Now, for my question:  The Fluent Registration API and Installers work swimmingly for auto-wiring scenarios (i.e. when I want Windsor to just figure out how to construct my object graphs).  Auto-wiring is the vast majority of IoC use cases out there, but what about when auto-wiring isn't possible?  In other words I have multiple implementations of a service and I need to tell Windsor how to construct parts of my object graph.  I've done this many times with the Xml Registration approach, but is there a more preferred approach these days?  I'm hesitant to go the Xml Registration approach as its future seems uncertain, but I don't know how else to accomplish this with Windsor.

My uses cases are:

- System needs to be able to swap implementations at QA-test (i.e.
  credit checks and fraud detection processing where we want to test
  without a dependency on a credit bureau API)
- Provider patterns in our
  system where we need to conditionally turn on and off different
  implementations at deploy-time.

This all seems very well suited for IoC and we have all the building blocks in place, but want to make sure I'm taking the most future-proof approach with Windsor.

**UPDATE:**
While I like the feature toggle approach, I recently discovered a Windsor feature that is very useful on this front - [Fallback Components](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-31.ashx?HL=fallback).  I'm leaving this edit here for anyone that might stumbled across this later.

Comment: Can you post the xml configuration that you are trying to mimic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuring your DI container completely through XML is error prone, verbose, and just too painful. The XML configuration possibilities are always a subset of what you can do with code based configuration; code is always more expressive.

Sometimes though your DI configuration depends on deploy-time configurations, but since the number of knobs you need are often fairly small, using a configuration flag is often a much better approach than polluting your configuration file with fully qualified type names.

Or let me put it differently, when you have large amounts of your DI configuration placed in your configuration file because your might want to change them at deploy time, please think again. Many of the changes need testing (by a developer) anyway, so there is no way you want someone from your operations team to fiddle around with that. And when you need a developer to look at it and verify it, what's the advantage of not having to recompile the project? Is this actually any quicker? A developer would still have to start the application anyway.

It is a false sense of flexibility and in fact a poor interface design (xml is the interface for your maintenance and operations department). BTW, are you the person that needs to document how the configuration file should be changed? 
Instead of describing the list of fully qualified type names that are valid somewhere in the middle of the xml file, wouldn't it be much easier of all you have to write is "place 'false' in this field to disable ..."?

Here is an example of how to use a configuration switch:

```cs
bool detectFraught =
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DetectFraud"] != "false";

container.Register(
    Component.For(typeof(IFraughtDetector)).ImplementedBy(
        detectFraught ? typeof(RealDectector) : typeof(FakeDetector));
```

See how the configuration switch is now simply a boolean flag. This makes the configuration file much more maintainable, since the configuration is now a simple boolean switch instead of a complete type name (that can be misspelled).

Of course doing the `["DetectFraud"] != "false"` isn't that nice by itself, but this can simply be solved by creating a strongly-typed configuration helper.

Comment: Steven - i agree.  i hated the xml config for this reason, but we looking for something at the framework level of solve this.  the reality is, this is a domain specific problem and it's best solved by me instead of the framework.  rather than have all the complexity of moving registration into a config file, just open up very specific config switches to conditionally load installers.  seems so simple - not sure why it wasn't more apparent this morning :)  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319263/174545) might help as well.  Allows you to dynamically, at runtime, provide an implementation.  Though, sounds like you don't need it that dynamically and it's a little less obvious what's going on.

Comment: Andy - yeah, we're using selectors currently and this works really well for runtime conditions.  i think what stephen is saying below better fits my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are no plans to obsolete or remove the XML config support in Windsor.

Yes, you are right, it isn't a preferred approach due to its numerous drawbacks.

Anything you can do in XML can be done in code (note that inverse is not true).

Also keep in mind XML is not all-or-nothing. There are many ways to achieve the scenarios you gave as examples without resorting to registration in XML.

- Feature toggles
- Conditional compilation
- if/else in your `installer` based on a appSettings flag
- others...

I've used each of them in different projects in the past.